# Group data by Year and Month

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
 1. customerID
 2. dateAdded
 3. productID
 4. quantity
```

The format of `dateAdded` is like this: `20180730` (`YearMonthDay`).

I want to group the rows in the table by year and month.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work. I still see rows with the same year and month repeated, but different day.

```
SELECT dateAdded
     , SUM(quantity) 
  FROM testTable 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(dateAdded, '%Y%m')
     , dateAdded 
 ORDER 
    BY dateAdded DESC
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not group by what you do not want the data to be grouped. Since you provide `dateAdded` as a parameter to be grouped with, it splits the data by `dateAdded` and you gain nothing out of year-month grouping. Remove the columns from select/groupby that you use for grouping like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateAdded, '%Y%m')
     , SUM(quantity) 
FROM testTable 
GROUP BY 
     DATE_FORMAT(dateAdded, '%Y%m')
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked. I will accept the answer in 2 minutes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you store `dateAdded` as 20180730, looks like it's a string, so it wont work with `DATE_FORMAT` function, you can use `SUBSTRING` instead

something like

```
SELECT dateAdded, SUM(quantity), SUBSTRING(dateAdded, 1, 6) as d 
  FROM testTable 
 GROUP BY d
 ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

Comment: I would caution against selecting by one thing and grouping by another. This is how trouble starts.

Comment: Unfortunately, you still have an unaggregated column in the select.

Comment: Your first answer didn't work for me due to unaggregated columns. I didn't try the modified solution because I used Andrius solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use `year` and `month` function

```
 SELECT Year(dateAdded) as YearOfDate,Month(dateAdded) as MonthOfdate,
         , SUM(quantity) as Qty
      FROM testTable 
     GROUP 
        BY Year(dateAdded), Month(dateAdded) 
     ORDER  BY dateAdded DESC
```